# Generate a report with account and 2 custom objects

Tags: reporting, custom-report-type

I have 2 custom objects(sales and service) which are related to accounts as a lookup and related to opportunities in a master detail.

i need to generate a report which shows under each account the list of sales and service records.

Not sure how i can build this relationship in report types

Answer (score 2):

You could do a [joined report](https://na12.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/reports_examples_joined.htm) which is just two reports that have common fields. One would be Accounts with Sales and the other would be Accounts with Service Records. You can then group across both blocks with Account name.

Comment: Thanks Daniel.. Does joined report go along with conga composer?

Comment: No, I don't think so. But, if you are using Conga, you can have two separate reports and pass both of them over to Conga for the merge.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your data model correctly you should be able to do this with one soql query and conga has something called "conga queries" which allow you to pull data from stored soql queries that you write instead of reports.

I believe this is available as a private appexchange package and you will need to contact Conga about activating it in your org (there isn't any additional cost).

Comment: I do not think conga supports nested templates/ nested queries for the above model he needs to soemthing like select id,(select id from services__c),(select id from sales__c) from account limit 1. This is not supported by conga nor can u embed table within a table with different tablestart: and tableend:. If there is a way to nest up the data i would be more happier and thankful if ypu post a sample query/ implemenation

Comment: @rao You can't do sub-queries in conga queries but you can use tablegroups to split tables by a field value and then just create a formula field with the groupings you want (basically like a map<string,list<Sobject>>).  

Now that I re-read the post I may have misunderstood data model. Thought there was account.service__c and account.sales__c lookup fields.